# How can I fix the lambda line to make my if work?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, lambda, filter

I am trying to make an if statement inside a lambda but the catch is I also trying to make all odd numbers to the third too, the lambda line is ignoring the i**3,

```py
numbers = range(1,10)

odd_numbers_to_the_third_2 = list(filter(lambda i : i**3 if i%2!=0 else None , numbers))
```

in the second line of the code I am trying to i**3 if its an odd number but the result shows the odd numbers without making it **3
I get [1,3,5,7,9] instead of [1,27,125,343,729]

Comment: [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) only filters items, as the name implies - it doesn't transform them. You need to perform the transformation separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as `filter()` just checks the list items and returns the values which satisfies the condition, you can use `map()` to do what you want:

1. this code:

```py
odd_numbers_to_the_third_2 = list(map(lambda i : i**3 if i%2!=0 else None , numbers))
```

with this output:

```py
[1, None, 27, None, 125, None, 343, None, 729]
```

2. or this one:

```py
odd_numbers_to_the_third_2 = list(map(lambda i : i**3 if i%2!=0 else None , list(filter(lambda i : i%2!=0, numbers ))))
```

for this output:

```py
[1, 27, 125, 343, 729]
```

Comment: You already filtered all odds, why do you need the `if` check again in your `map`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a comprehension:

```
>>> odd_numbers_to_the_third_2 = [i**3 for i in numbers if i%2 != 0]
>>> odd_numbers_to_the_third_2
[1, 27, 125, 343, 729]
```

Using `filter` and `map`:

```
>>> odd_numbers_to_the_third_2 = list(map(lambda x: x**3, filter(lambda x: x%2 != 0, numbers)))
>>> odd_numbers_to_the_third_2
[1, 27, 125, 343, 729]
```

Comment: `x%2 != 0` is just `x%2`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` to get the number cubed, then filter out `None` values:

```
odd_numbers_to_the_third_2 = list(filter(bool,map(lambda i : i**3 if i%2!=0 else None, numbers)))
```

Or, use a generator expression to only apply `map` to odd numbers and discard the rest:

```
odd_numbers_to_the_third_2 = list(map(lambda i : i**3, (num for num in numbers if num%2!=0)))
```

Or don't use `map`/`filter` at all:

```
odd_numbers_to_the_third_2 = [num**3 for num in numbers if num%2 != 0]
```

All approaches output:

```
[1, 27, 125, 343, 729]
```

Comment: I would do the first example in reverse: filter odds and cube all odds.

Comment: That's better indeed, I just started with something that's close to OP's existing code.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) doesn't perform any actual transformation, it just uses your `lambda` to decide what to return.

Instead I would use a list comprehension with conditional:

```
numbers = range(1,10)
odd_numbers_to_the_third_2 = [i**3 for i in numbers if i%2 != 0]
```

Comment: it doesn't do what is needed

Comment: Whoops, does now

Answer (score 0):

[`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) filters and does not transform list. [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) is for transformation.

So, you should filter first to get all odd numbers and map to transform:

```
list(map(lambda x: x ** 3, filter(lambda i: i % 2, numbers)))
```

Ideally, you should use list-comprehension which is proven effective than `map`/`filter` `lambda` combinations:

```
[x ** 3 for x in numbers if x % 2]
```